# What is the difference between the function Ember.computed() and function().property()?

Tags: ember.js

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  // these will be supplied by `create`
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName'),

  fullName:Ember.computed('firstName','lastName', function() {
     return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');    
  }
});
```

What is the difference between the function Ember.computed() or function().property()?

Why there are two ways (functions) to declares the function to be a computed property?
What are the differences, benefits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ember.computed()` is an (clean) [alternative](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_alternate-invocation) to `function().property()` in case you are [disabling prototype extensions](http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/).

Comment: Ok thank you, which one would you recommend. Ember.computed()  or function().property()

Comment: I prefer `Ember.computed()`.